# Adding shell if statement inside lftp

Tags: bash, sftp, lftp

I'm trying to use SFTP to copy some files from one server to another, this task should run everyweek. The script I use :

```
    HOST='sftp://my.server.com'
    USER='user1'
    PASSWORD='passwd'
    DIR=$HOSTNAME

    REMOTE_DIR='/home/remote' 
    LOCAL_DIR='/home/local'     

    # LFTP via SFTP connexion
    lftp -u "$USER","$PASSWORD" $HOST <<EOF

    # changing directory
    cd "$REMOTE_DIR"

    $(if [ ! -d "$DIR" ]; then
     mkdir  $DIR

    fi)

    put -O "$REMOTE_DIR"/$DIR  "$LOCAL_DIR"/uploaded.txt

    EOF
```

My issue is that **put** is executed without taking in consideration the result of **if statment**.

PS : The error message I got is the following :

> put: Access failed: No such file (/home/backups/myhost/upload.txt)

Comment: I think it's a little bit unclear what you want. Should `put` only be executed when the code in the if statement is executed?

Comment: The if statement, verify if a folder with the sender hostname exists or no, if yes it will send the file to that specific folder, otherwise, it will create one.  The idea is to create a folder for each host sending files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[LFTP](https://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html) has no `if` statement!

What you are doing here?

> ```
> lftp -u "$USER","$PASSWORD" $HOST <<EOF
> cd "$REMOTE_DIR"
> $(if [ ! -d "$DIR" ]; then
>  mkdir  $DIR
> fi)
> put -O "$REMOTE_DIR"/$DIR  "$LOCAL_DIR"/uploaded.txt
> EOF
> ```

You call a sub command in a here document. The sub command is executed locally before `lftp` is started and its output is pasted in the here document, which gets passed to `lftp`. This works just, because `mkdir` has no output. You do not call `mkdir` on the ftp server. You call the `mkdir` of your local shell. Effectively it is the same as if you put the `if` statement before the `lftp` execution.

```
if [ ! -d "$DIR" ]; then
  mkdir $DIR
fi
lftp -u "$USER","$PASSWORD" $HOST <<EOF
cd "$REMOTE_DIR"
put -O "$REMOTE_DIR"/$DIR  "$LOCAL_DIR"/uploaded.txt
EOF
```

What you are trying to do, does not work. You have to think about a different solution.

Right now I have no FTP server to test it, but it might be possible to use the `-f` option of LFTP's `mkdir`. I assume that it may work like the `-f` option of the Unix `rm` command. Try this:

```
lftp -u "$USER","$PASSWORD" $HOST <<EOF
cd "$REMOTE_DIR"
mkdir -f "$DIR"
put -O "$REMOTE_DIR"/$DIR  "$LOCAL_DIR"/uploaded.txt
EOF
```

*Update:* It works as supposed. The creation of a directory, which exist already, throws no error, if you use the option `-f`:

```
lftp anonymous@localhost:/pub> mkdir -f dir
mkdir ok, `dir' created
lftp anonymous@localhost:/pub> mkdir -f dir
lftp anonymous@localhost:/pub> ls
drwx------    2 116      122          4096 Aug 10 12:04 dir
```

Maybe you `lftp` client is outdated. I tested it with Debian 9.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I tried mkdir -f but it doesn't work, **mkdir: invalid option -- 'f' **    Will look for another way to do it.

Comment: LFTP | Version 4.4.8 | Copyright (c) 1996-2013 Alexander V. Lukyanov

Comment: Debian 9 uses 4.7.4 from 2016.